# How to print a file to the printer running on standard TCP/IP port?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

can any one tell me how to print a file using command in windows?
 I tried using below command

```
print /D:\\localhost\myprinter  testfile
```

but its giving the error: unable to initialize device \\localhost\myprinter

Any suggestions are appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest way is to use the `lpr` command. If it's not loaded on your system, follow [these instructions](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=136832).

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide printer name after **/D:**
Like `print /D:"Microsoft XPS Document Writer" testfile.txt`

You can determine printer name by running the following command in Windows 7 command line:
`C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -l`

Comment: Hi @Nikolai first of all thanks for your reply,and  I am using in same way(print /D:"VP1"  C:\Users\Prasad\Desktop\test.txt ) but it is giving me the  error :Unable to initialize device VP1.

Comment: @prasad Try to quote printer name.

Comment: yeah it is quoted ,see in above command

Comment: Can you add results of the C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -l command?

Comment: I am not able to execute the above command ,can you please tell that how to execute the command "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -l"

Comment: You have VB scripts under C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts directory. Maybe you have different locale other then en-US so you should  substitute it in path. You need to find file `prnmngr.vbs` and run  it with `-l` parameter from the command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23049/discussion-between-prasad-and-nikolai).

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in printer format, you can use the following command to send it to the printer:

LPR -S printer_IP_address -P queue_name filename

The queue_name is printer-specific, but most modern printers do not really care what it is. If it's an HP printer, use "raw". This will work with most others as well, even those, like Xerox, that use specific names to select printer features (e.g. PS tells the printer to use the PostScript interpreter)

If the file is not in printer format (i.e. it's a Word doc, a PDF, a JPEG, etc), then use an application and a printer driver to print it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775908(v=ws.10).aspx)...

If the printer is connected to parallel port 1, you can

```
print /d:lpt1 <file>
```

If it is a network printed, you can redirect lpt1 (or lpt2) to the printer first:

```
net use lpt1: \\remotehost\myprinter
print /d:lpt1 <file>
```

Comment: Hi @Werner Henze ,thank you so much for your response,but actually I am not using remote printer ,just using local printer which is running on TCP/IP port ,not on LPT.In this case how can I print the file?Please let me know..

Comment: @Prasad Then just replace "remotehost" with "localhost". You should be able to map a locally connected printer. But looking at the other answers I think that Nikolai gave the right answer. That worked for me.

Comment: yeah I tried that too(i.e map using localhost ),but getting the error   System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.